# log into a VM in Azure using my Azure AD credentials via RDP

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, entra-id

I would like to be able to log into a VM in Azure using my Azure AD credentials via RDP. The login should be done over the internet from MAC and Linux clients (clients are not members in Azure AD). For security I use Just in Time Access.
MFA is not activated
Is this possible? How can I implement the project?

When I set it up, I get this message
[image: Error]

Thanks for the support

Stefan

Comment: Please specify what OS and version you are trying to connect to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was the enabeld MFA in the MFA Portal. Only a policy in conditional access will not work.

Thanks for your support

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Read the fine print: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/howto-vm-sign-in-azure-ad-windows#requirements

Only Windows machines that are joined/registered to the same tenant are supported. What you're doing is not a supported scenario.